# Arbelos - Pappus chain radius of tangent circles

Tags: geometry, mobius-inversion

I would like to determine radius' of pappus chain circles which are tangent to Arbelos. Below I will put some photos from one book that showed how to determine it. The only thing that i don't understand, is the last line of determination of $r_n$. I don't get why $r_n$ would be equal to $\frac{k}{k_n} \cdot r'$.

Figure:
[image]

Determination:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is given and what is required? When primed sigma straight lines touch in bilinear transformation 
$(\Sigma_{1},\Sigma_{1}^{'}),(\Sigma_{2},\Sigma_{2}^{'})$  as shown, what are $r_n?$ .. is the question right?

Comment: Yes,exactly @Narasimham

Comment: Start with  lines and find their inversions, evaluating constants of  each set. from pole O. What is the power of $x^2+y^2=2xc ?$